# How can I populate specific columns from sidebar?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

I've created a sidebar that populates columns from column "A" to column "G" with data in my spreadsheet.
But the problem is that I need specific columns to be populated. I need data to start populating column from "E" to "J" and 1 separate column "L". These columns are colored with grey color.
[image: screenshot]

How do I specify those columns?

**My function is:**

```
function appendData(data){
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Аркуш32");
ws.appendRow([data.product,data.clientname,data.partnername,data.adress,data.phone,data.email,data.source]);     
     }
```

**My HTML is:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">local_mall</i>
      <input id="product" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="product">Товар</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
      <input id="clientname" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="clientname">ПІП клієнта</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">assignment_ind</i>
      <input id="partnername" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="partnername">Назва партнера</label>
    </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">home</i>
      <input id="adress" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="adress">Адреса</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
      <input id="phone" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="phone">Номер телефону</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">mail</i>
      <input id="email" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="email">Емейл</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">hearing</i>
      <input id="source" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="source">Джерело</label>
    </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
       <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="btn">Додати
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- end row -->
    
</div>

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
   var productBox = document.getElementById("product");
   var clientnameBox = document.getElementById("clientname");
   var partnernameBox = document.getElementById("partnername");
   var adressBox = document.getElementById("adress");
   var phoneBox = document.getElementById("phone");
   var emailBox = document.getElementById("email");
   var sourceBox = document.getElementById("source");
   
   document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",addRecord);
   function addRecord(){
   var data = {
      product: productBox.value,
      clientname: clientnameBox.value,
      partnername: partnernameBox.value,
      adress: adressBox.value,
      phone: phoneBox.value,
      email: emailBox.value,
      source: sourceBox.value
   };
   
   google.script.run.appendData(data);
      productBox.value = "";
      clientnameBox.value = "";
      partnernameBox.value = "";
      adressBox.value = "";
      phoneBox.value = "";
      emailBox.value = "";
      sourceBox.value = "";
      
   }
     
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, how do I make the sidebar populate cells whether with a click on the button or by pressing Enter?

Comment: Try splice method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question very old, but anyway...

If you don't mind to erase the cells A..D and K, all you need is to add several empty elements `''` into one line this way:

```
ws.appendRow(['','','','',data.product,data.clientname,data.partnername,data.adress,data.phone,data.email,'',data.source]);
```

If you have some data in the cells A..D and K that you want to keep, it will need a little bit more complicated solution.

Answer (score 1):

This example has a text box for holding the select range in a1Notation and a select button to select the active range.  It has a text box for entering word text with spaces between the words which are used as delimiters and a button for writing the words of the text into the cells of the selected range.

GS Code:

```
function showSideBarDialog() {
  var html='<html><head>';;
  html+='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>';
  html+='</head><body>';
  html+='<input type="text" id="select" placeholder="Select Range and Press Select" size="40" /><br /><input type="button" value="Select"onClick="selectRange();" />';
  html+='<textarea rows="4" cols="30" id="txt1" placeholder="Enter some word text (spaces required)"></textarea><br /><input type="button" value="Write" onClick="postText();" />';
  html+='<script>function selectRange(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(r){$("#select").val(r);}).selectRange();}';
  html+='function postText(){google.script.run.postText({text:$("#txt1").val(),range:$("#select").val()});}';
  html+='</script>';
  html+='</body></html>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setTitle('Write to Range'));
}

function selectRange() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  return rg.getA1Notation();
}

function postText(obj) {
  var tA=obj.text.split(' ');
  console.log(obj.text);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(obj.range);
  var vs=rg.getValues();
  var n=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vs.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vs[i].length;j++) {
      if(n<tA.length) {
        vs[i][j]=tA[n++];
      }else{
        rg.setValues(vs);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  rg.setValues(vs);
}
```

Animation:

[image]

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. 
Text that I put in the sidebar should appear in specific columns